# Das Partizip Perfekt von dreisilbigen Wörtern

Tags: past-participle

Manfred Spitzer erklärt in seinen Büchern und Vorträgen, dass Menschen sich die Grammatik ihrer Muttersprache nicht über Einzelfälle, sondern über allgemeine (unbewusste) Regeln merken.

Dazu lässt er die Leser und Hörer Phantasiewörter ins Partizip Perfekt setzen, und zwar ein zweisilbiges Wort wie "quaffen" und ein dreisilbiges Wort auf "-ieren" wie "flagieren".

Er behauptet dann, dass das Ergebnis "gequafft" und "flagiert" bedeutet, dass Wörter auf "-ieren" eine Ausnahme bilden.

Ich glaube aber, dass das mit "-ieren" nichts zu tun hat, sondern rein damit, dass es sich um ein dreisilbiges Wort ohne Vorsilbe handelt.

Um diese Vermutung zu überprüfen, bräuchte ich aber mehr echt dreisilbige Zeitwörter, was im Deutschen selten ist.

Meine Frage ist nun:
Liege ich mit meiner Vermutung zu der Dreisilbigkeit richtig? Kann mir jemand ein paar Beispiele für echt dreisilbige Zeitwörter geben, die meine Vermutung unterstützen oder widerlegen? Oder gibt es das sogar als Grammatikregel in einem guten Grammatikbuch? Oder hat das Zurückführen auf "-ieren" (gute oder schlechte) Tradition?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Mit "Ausnahme" meinst Du, dass das Partizip Perfekt ohne die Vorsilbe "ge-" gebildet wird?

Hier ein paar dreisilbige Verben mit Partizip Perfekt (teilweise mit Vorsilbe, die aber nicht abtrennbar ist - zu **pro**-phezeien gibt es kein vorsilbenloses "phezeizen" - wie steht es mit "(a)dressieren"?):

- adressieren -> **adressiert**
- antworten -> geantwortet
- arbeiten -> gearbeitet
- beginnen -> **begonnen**
- bewegen -> **bewegt**
- flankieren -> **flankiert**
- geschehen -> geschehen
- gewinnen -> gewonnen
- mäandern -> **mäandert**
- prophezeien -> **prophezeit**
- studieren -> **studiert**
- tangieren -> **tangiert**

Fett sind alle Partizip-Perfekt-Formen markiert, die ohne (zusätzliches) "ge-" gebildet sind. Das trifft also für alle angeführten Verben zu, die auf "-ieren" enden, aber noch zusätzlich auf weitere Verben.

[canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-V/Texte/Partizip-mit-ohne-ge.html) bestätigt im Prinzip die Ausnahmestellung von Verben auf "-ieren" und ergänzt zwei weitere Verbgruppen:

- Verben mit unbetonten Vorsilben wie be-, er-, ent-, ge-, ver-, zer-;
- trennbare Verben, die mit einem Verb aus der ersten Gruppe ("-ieren", unbetonte Vorsilbe) gebildet wurden.

Die Rolle der Betonung zeigt sich auch in meiner knappen obigen Auswahl: **ánt**-worten und **ár**-beiten wird auf der ersten Silbe betont, alle anderen Verben auf der zweiten oder im Ausnahmefall auf der dritten (z.B. pro-phe-**zéi**-en). Insbesondere werden wohl alle Verben auf "-ieren" auf der vorletzten Silbe betont, also jener, die mit dem ie von "-ieren" gebildet wird: flan-**kíe**-ren, stu-**díe**-ren, tan-**gie**-ren.

canoo.net hat übrigens eine schöne [Liste von Verben, deren Partizip Perfekt ohne "ge-" gebildet wird](http://canoonet.eu/services/InflectionRules/Controller?entryClass=Cat%20V&matchRules=(BesTab%20Partizip-ohne-ge-1)&resultId=2219ac).

Comment: Bei der canoo.net-Liste werden zwei Verben gar nicht aufgeführt! kra**kee**len (hat krakeelt) und sti**bi**tzen (hat stibitzt)! Interessante Beispiele waren: *promoten*, *interviewen*, *zweckentfremden*.

Comment: "adressieren" ist freilich viersilbig.

Answer (score 3):

Mir fallen nicht besonders viele dreisilbige Verben ein, die nicht mit einer Vorsilbe wie *ver*, *aus*, *be* etc. gebildet sind. Das Partizip Perfekt wird bei diesen Beispielen mit "ge-" gebildet:

- arbeiten: gearbeitet
- ängstigen: geängstigt
- demütigen: gedemütigt

Ich nehme also an, dass der Autor nicht ganz falsch mit seiner Aussage über *-ieren*-verben liegt.

Bei Verben mit *bestimmten Vorsilben* wird – wie bei Wörtern mit weniger Silben – das Partizip Perfekt ohnehin nicht mit *"ge-"* als zusätzliche Vorsilbe gebildet:

- erwähnen: erwähnt (nicht *geerwähnt* oder *ergewähnt*)
- vergessen: vergessen

Bei anderen Vorsilben wird das *ge-* nach der Vorsilbe eingefügt:

- austreten: ausgetreten
- beifügen: beigefügt

Answer (score 2):

ich bin seit über 20 Jahren DaF-Lehrerin und da muss ich natürlich so etwas meinen Schülern erklären können. 
Am liebsten mach' ich das mit einer Tabelle.
Nun hatte ich nach: ruomoren, prophezeien u.a. Verben gesucht, wobei ich mich fragte, warum haben DIESE Verben kein ge-??? 
Und so kam ich zu eurer Seite und dann bei der Suche nach einer Antwort auch noch in einem Grammatikbuch: Schüler Duden Übungsbücher 1975 – Übungen zur deutschen Sprache I – Grammatische Übungen ISBN 3-411-01336-2[image: trennbare und untrennbare Verben]

Also alle Fragen werden durch die beiliegende Tabelle geklärt. 
Wenn ein Verb mit –ieren kommt, erkläre ich meinen DaF-Schülern, dass das eine Gruppe ist, die immer regelmäßig konjugiert und regelmäßig in allen 3 Zeitformen ist, und von daher das Verb immer den gleichen Stamm behält. Die Endung ist im Partizip II immer mit –t-, genauso wie für alle regelmäßigen Verben:
Organisieren, studieren, kommunizieren, radieren, kopieren, programmieren, telefonieren, sich genieren, pausieren, perfektionieren, sozialisieren, probieren, usw.
Wird zu: organisiert, studiert…..   ohne –ge
Ich lege dir eine Tabelle bei, wo du das und die nicht trennbaren Vorsilben siehst, die immer ohne ge- gebildet werden, wenn es sich um regelmäßige oder unregelmäßige Verben handelt.

Und auf meine Frage: hatte jemand hier oben die Lösung gefunden: das hängt von der Betonung ab.

Comment: Das ist DaF? Deutsch Amerikanische Freundschaft? Die Niederländische LWK-Marke wird wohl auch nicht gemeint sein.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Deutsch als Fremdsprache.

Comment: Ich nehme an, die *downvotes* kommen davon, dass die Essenz nicht textuell zusammengefasst ist, und die Referenz auf ein vermutlich nicht mehr erhältliches Buch verweist. Ich finde das trotzdem etwas hart.

Comment: Meines Erachtens ist dies die Beste der Antworten. Deutsch Lerndende werden eine allgemeine Regel spannender finden als nur ein paar Beispiele. Außerdem meinte der FS: `Oder gibt es das sogar als Grammatikregel in einem guten Grammatikbuch?` Voilà.