# Morphologie - Werkzeuge, Datenbanken, Suchwerkzeuge?

Tags: online-resource, morphology, resource

[theis Frage zur Partizipbildung](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1720/das-partizip-perfekt-von-dreisilbigen-w%C3%B6rtern) hat mich darauf gebracht, nach Werkzeugen zu [morphologischen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphologie_(Linguistik)) Fragen zu stöbern. [canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/) scheint ja eine Suche nach den Kategorien zu ermöglichen, die einzelnen Lemmata in der Rubrik "Besonderheiten" zugeordnet sind (im obigen Beispiel: "Verben mit Partizip ohne 'ge-'".

Gibt es noch mehr ähnliche Angebote? Gibt es kommerzielle Werkzeuge (Datenbanken) oder ähnliches? Morphologische Suche ist ja auch Teil von fachspezifischen Datenbanken, z.B. Bibleworks. Google liefert für die deutsche Sprache schon mal als einen der ersten Treffer eine [kleine Übersicht](http://cornelia.siteware.ch/linguistik/morphologie.html). Was gibt es sonst noch?

P.S.: Ich kenne mich mit den stackexchange.com-Seiten noch nicht so gut aus - gibt es hier die Möglichkeit, kooperativ eine Wiki-artige zentrale Linkliste zu solchen Angeboten zu erstellen und zu pflegen?

**Links**

- [canoonet](http://canoonet.eu/)
- [Digitales Wörterbuch der deutschen Sprache](https://www.dwds.de/)

Comment: Zu deinem P.S.: Ich habe die Frage in eine "community wiki"-Frage umgewandelt. Siehe http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts

Comment: @splattne - prima, danke! Genau das was ich gesucht habe :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Das Institut für Deutsche Sprache in Mannheim bietet mit [Cosmas II](https://cosmas2.ids-mannheim.de/cosmas2-web/) ein Werkzeug an, das unter anderem erlaubt, Suchanfragen mit morphosyntaktischen Annotationen zu stellen. Die Registrierung ist kostenlos, aber der Service richtet sich an Sprachwissenschaftler und die recht schwierige Suchsyntax erfordert entsprechendes Vorwissen und eine Einarbeitung.